# Exercise with for cycle

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I'm new to the forum I'm trying to learn Javascript I should do this simple exercise with the for loop, in practice given an array containing email addresses, on a variable entered by the user via prompt I have to verify that the inserted email is contained in the array and then print the relative affirmative message on video, I did something like that but it doesn't work and I don't understand where I'm wrong ....

```
// initialize an array with a mailing list
var mail = ['mail1', 'mail2', 'mail3'];

var mail_user = prompt ('Enter your mail');

for (var i = 0; i <mail.lenght; i ++) {

    if (mail_user == email) {
        document.writeln ('Your email address is correct')               
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please refrain from using tags which aren't appropriate.

Comment: Please post actual code...the code above is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
// initialize an array with a mailing list
var mail = ['mail1', 'mail2', 'mail3'];

var mail_user = prompt ('Enter your mail');

for (var i = 0; i <mail.length; i ++) {

    if (mail_user == mail[i]) {
        document.writeln ('Your email address is correct')
    }
 }
```

I updated your `if` statement

---

Or you can use `foreach`

```
mail.forEach(function(email) {
    if (mail_user == email) {
        document.whiteln ('Your email address is correct')
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use for loop, but you don't actually iterate over the array. If you want to compare the input email adress you have to retrieve the the particular ones from the array, which is done by calling `mail[i]`

```
var mail = ['mail1', 'mail2', 'mail3'];

var mail_user = prompt ('Enter your mail');

for (var i = 0; i <mail.length; i ++) {

    if (mail_user == mail[i]) {
        console.log('Your email address is correct')
    }
 }
```